# How do you implement OkHttpDataSourceFactory in exoplayer?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-videoview, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

How do you implement OkHttpDataSourceFactory in exoplayer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked all over and I could not find good answer on how to implement the OkHttpDataSourceFactory. Finally found an [example](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5038#issuecomment-434991743) in one of the issues on how someone else went about it. It seemed simple enough. I finally got it down to this.

```
val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
val client = builder.build()
val okHttpDataSourceFactory = OkHttpDataSourceFactory(client)
val player = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context)
        .setMediaSourceFactory(DefaultMediaSourceFactory(okHttpDataSourceFactory))
        .build()
```

You can treat the builder as you normally would. In my case I need to add an interceptor to add

```
builder.addInterceptor { chain ->
    val newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", token))
            .build()
    chain.proceed(newRequest)
}
```

Comment: deprecated, suggest to use  OkHttpDataSource.Factory https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1157